# How can I run Silk-Test (4Test language) for 3 times and get the data from a list everytime? (everytime a different person)

Tags: automated-tests, silktest

CustomerSearch.Customers.Select ("ARUNDEL, CLAUDE")
How do I get a different one from list everytime?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

```
    [ ] INTEGER i
    [-] for(i = 1; i < 4; ++i)
        [ ] TestApplication.ListBoxDialog.TheListBox.Select(i)
        [ ] String sList = TestApplication.ListBoxDialog.TheListBox.GetItemText(i)
        [ ] Print("List Box Selection = " + sList)
```

John

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help!